# In animate() function, any difference between ({"marginLeft":(-1*width)+"px"}) and ({"marginLeft":"-512px"})

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to realize the marquee effect, and find if I set `listone.animate({"marginLeft":"-512px"})`, it did not work correctly; Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function marqueen(){

        var listone=$("ul").find("a").eq(0);
        var width=$("img").children().eq(0).width();

        listone.animate({"marginLeft":(-1*width)+"px"},1000,function(){
        $(this).parent("li").css("margin-left","0").appendTo("ul");

      });
    }
    setInterval(marqueen,2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the width is dynamic. Which mean on shrinking of browser or expanding or in case of responsive view different `width` will be registered from this

```
var width=$("img").children().eq(0).width();
```

So every time `marginLeft` will be a different value

`({“marginLeft”:(-1*width)+“px”})`

In `({“marginLeft”:“-512px”})` the value is always fixed to -`512px` & independent of any other paramater

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the pictures width is fix, it is the same picture and equal to 512px;